# Можно ли поставить запятую... перед скобками?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, скобки

С одной стороны, **[Грамота](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FrD6.jpg)** говорит, что категорически нельзя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, с другой стороны, здесь спорный момент и хочется поставить перед скобками. Пример, о котором я говорю:

*Когда открыли Плутон, (тогда) его классифицировали как планета*.

Ясное дело, перед *тогда*, не находящемся в скобках, запятая ставилась бы. А если заскобировать? Момент спорный. Расскажите, совы, что да как.

Comment: Наверное, правильнее будет так: «…классифицировали как планет**у**»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В правилах Розенталя отмечен такой случай.

> **Примечание.** Знаки препинания, которые стоят на месте «разрыва» предложения вставной конструкцией, выделяемой скобками, помещаются после скобок...
>
> В редких случаях, когда вставная конструкция явно относится ко второй части предложения, внутри которой она находится, нужный знак препинания перед открывающей скобкой сохраняется...

*В старинны годы люди были

Совсем не то, что в наши дни;

**(Коль в мире есть любовь)** любили

Чистосердечнее они.*
М. Лермонтов. Незабудка

Думаю, что ваше предложение можно оформить так (при условии, что "тогда" — это предполагаемый союз, который, естественно, относится только ко второй части; обычно такие конструкции встречаются при объяснении пунктуации, в том числе и на нашем сайте):

*Когда открыли Плутон, (тогда) его классифицировали как планету.*
Или так:
*Когда открыли Плутон, (тогда) он был классифицирован как планета.*

[Вставные предложения и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125)
[Тогда](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1054618)

Answer (score 1):

Нисколько момент не спорный.

Никогда и ни за какие коврижки запятая перед скобками не ставится.

Comment: Это не совсем так. К примеру, при построении схем предложений при их синтаксическом разборе запятая перед скобками (в которых заключено придаточное) может стоять на вполне законных основаниях. См. пример: **[– =], (– =), (который =).**

Comment: Слава, спасибо. Дайте, пожалуйста, свой ответ - буду рада прочитать! Пример мне непонятен!

Comment: Сейчас не смогу. Спать хочу!  Может, утром дам… если никто до того меня не опередит.